# Workings of top and ps commands

Tags: linux, command-line

How do the commands `top` and `ps` calculate CPU utilization using the `/proc/[$pid]/stat` file? Also how do they obtain memory utilization information about the process?

Comment: If you have two unrelated questions, post two questions.  Don't combine them just because you had them at the same time.  I've removed your second question.  If you want to ask it, open a new question.

Comment: I'd recommend just reading the source for the procps package.  It's pretty reasonable.  I think the answer is in the file `proc/sysinfo.c`

Comment: or more simply do a strace on the ps and top commands and find whereabouts of the files they look at, besides it is a implementation of procfs on Linux. The many parameters like VSZ or RSS are not properly calculated. I would suggest to look at `pmap -[dx]` command for more process specific memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do "just reading the source for the procps package"

What package(s) is/are `ps` and `top` in?

```
dpkg -S top| grep '/top$'
dpkg -S ps|grep '/ps$'
```

I have `apt-src` installed, do you?

```
dpkg -S apt-src
```

Look at the versions of procps and apt-src

```
dpkg -l procps apt-src
```

Get the source for the `procps` package

```
apt-src install procps
```

See what we got:

```
ls -ld procps*
```

`cd` into `procps-3.2.8` (or whatever version you downloaded) and look at the `Makefile`, and all files named with UPPER CASE, like `README*`, `INSTALL`, etc, and then read `*.h` and `*.c`, and consider executing `make`.

Answer (score 0):

Read this for good pointers on memory usage & calculation on Linux

http://virtualthreads.blogspot.com/2006/02/understanding-memory-usage-on-linux.html

http://virtualthreads.blogspot.com/2006/02/re-memory-usage-on-linux.html